# Magento2 custom attribute default value

Tags: attributes, eav-attributes

Are default values for custom attributes taken into account *at all*?

1. Create a yes-no/dropdown/text attribute, set a defautl value, add it to an attribute set.
2. Open a poduct to edit it.

Expected result: The custom attribute has the given default value.

Actual result: The custom attribute has no value.

Why does this not work?

Comment: Can you share the code source please? Can you define verison of Magento

Answer (score 4):

Default values won't be applied to the existing entities, a default value will only set on an entity when an entity is saved.

Comment: Would be nice if Magento could get this default value if the result of getData is null, seems a bit tedious to have to do this in a import or saving all products by hand.

Comment: @DWils You can write a custom script just to save the product.

Comment: Yea but to do this for every product? Would take a long time if the store has a lot of products. It would be better if the indexer can find the default value if its not in the product.

Comment: @DWils Or you can write direct SQL query in your database to store the default value for existing products.